# How to create OR blocks containing multiple criterias with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have multiple criterias constructed out of criterions and I would like to create a disjunction between them.

```
Criteria criteria1 = hibernateSession.createCriteria(MyClass);
criteria1.add(Restrictions.eq(field1, value1));
criteria1.add(Restrictions.eq(field2, value2));
criteria1.add(Restrictions.ne(field3, value3));
```

Which will create something like `Where field1 = value1 and field2 = value and field3 != value3`.

Then,

```
Criteria criteria2 = hibernateSession.createCriteria(MyClass);
criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq(field4, value4));
criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq(field5, value5));
```

Which will create something like `Where field4 = value4 and field5 = value5`.

My end goal here is to create a disjunction between `criteria1` and `criteria2` to have `Where (field1 = value1 and field2 = value and field3 != value3) OR (field4 = value4 and field5 = value5)`.

I know about the disjunction / conjonction in hibernate, however, they only accept criterions (and not criterias).

Have any of you achieved something similar before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two AND criterions.
Add them to the criteria as an OR.

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(MyClass);
Criterion rest1= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(field1, value1), 
           Restrictions.eq(field2, value2),
           Restrictions.ne(field3, value3));
Criterion rest2= Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(field4, value4),
           Restrictions.eq(field5, value5));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(rest1, rest2));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It'll work for the example I gave. However, I am looking for something more generic where I can create a disjunction between a list of criterias. Do you have any thoughts on how to do it ?

Comment: Sorry, I know of no way to do it via multiple criteria's (not certain it's possible). Perhaps the best way to make it generic for you is to work with Criterions and later build the criteria with a disjunction against the Criterion